# gdb is very slow when running with netbeans and c++

Tags: c++, netbeans, gdb

I am trying to debug a c++ linux program using netbeans and its very slow.

when looking at the  netbeans debugger console, I see that it's using gdb and making it printout a lot of information about call stack and variables. I don't need all the information, how do i make netbeans stop asking for it?

More specifically. Netbeans keep calling stack-list-arguments. my stack is very verbose, so is causes about 10 seconds delay for each single step

Comment: Just stop using netbeans, and use gdb directly?

Comment: Useless, I don't think that my little noggin is capable of using gdb directly. Netbeans has proved to be huge timesaver - I wish i could just fix that little problem.

Comment: Well, in case you decide to learn, it isn't that hard. There are tutorials (like [this](http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/)), and  you usually just need six commands: `break`, `run`, `continue`, `next`, `step` and `print`